# Default value in react hook form useField array

Tags: django-rest-framework, material-ui, autocomplete, react-hook-form, yup

I'm using django hyperlinked model serialiser on the backend and reactjs, mui, Yup, react-hook-form on the frontend.

I have a dynamic form using mui autocomplete. I'm able to post new data to the backend.

I have a challenge editing existing data. I can render the data but I'm not able to change the default value back to url if the user didn't modify that particular field. If a field is clicked, onChange fires and I'm able to pass validation

Yup Schema

```
const schema = Yup.object().shape({
        effective_date: Yup.date("YYYY-MM-DD").required('Effective date is required'),
        expense_lines: Yup.array()
            .min(1, "Enter at least one expense line")
            .of(
                Yup.object()
                    .shape({
                        type: Yup.string('Must be a string').required('Type is required'),
                        machine: Yup.string('Must be a string').required('Machine is required'),
                        driver: Yup.string('Must be a string').required('Driver is required'),
                        amount: Yup.number('Must be a number').typeError('Amount must be a number').required('Amount is required'),
                    }).required("Expense line is required")
            ),
    });
```

React Hook Form

```
const {handleSubmit, reset, control, formState, register, watch, getValues, setValue} = useForm({
resolver: yupResolver(schema),
defaultValues: {
effective_date: dayjs(),
status: 0
}});

const {fields, append, remove} = useFieldArray({name: 'expense_lines', control});
```

Form

```
{fields.map((item, index) => (
<Grid container sx={{mb: 3}} key={item.id} spacing={1}>
<Grid item xs={12} md={3}>
   <Controller
   name={`expense_lines.${index}.type`}
   control={control}
   render={({
   field: {onChange, value},
   fieldState: {error},
   formState,
   }) => (
   <Stack spacing={1}>
      <Autocomplete
      sx={{mt: 1}}
      options={expensesTypes ? expensesTypes.results : []}
      getOptionLabel={option => option ? option.name : ''}
      isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option?.url == value?.url}
      id="autocomplete"
      blurOnSelect
      disablePortal
      onChange={(e, value) => onChange(value?.url)}
      renderInput={(params) => (
      <TextField {...params}
      helperText={error ? error.message : null}
      error={!!error}
      variant="outlined"
      label={"Type"}
      />
      )}
      value={value || null}
      />
   </Stack>
   )}
   />
</Grid>
<Grid item xs={12} md={3}>
   <Controller
   name={`expense_lines.${index}.machine`}
   control={control}
   render={({
   field: {onChange, value},
   fieldState: {error},
   formState,
   }) => (
   <Stack spacing={1}>
      <Autocomplete
      sx={{mt: 1}}
      options={machines ? machines.results : []}
      getOptionLabel={option => option ? option.reg_no : ''}
      isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option?.url === value?.url}
      id="autocomplete"
      blurOnSelect
      disablePortal
      onChange={(e, value) => onChange(value?.url)}
      renderInput={(params) => (
      <TextField {...params}
      helperText={error ? error.message : null}
      error={!!error}
      variant="outlined"
      label={"Truck"}
      />
      )}
      value={value || null}
      />
   </Stack>
   )}
   />
</Grid>
<Grid item xs={12} md={3}>
   <Controller
   name={`expense_lines.${index}.driver`}
   control={control}
   render={({
   field: {onChange, value},
   fieldState: {error},
   formState,
   }) => (
   <Stack spacing={1}>
      <Autocomplete
      sx={{mt: 1}}
      options={drivers ? drivers.results : []}
      getOptionLabel={option => option ? option.full_name : ''}
      isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option?.url === value?.url}
      id="autocomplete"
      blurOnSelect
      disablePortal
      onChange={(e, value) => onChange(value?.url)}
      renderInput={(params) => (
      <TextField {...params}
      helperText={error ? error.message : null}
      error={!!error}
      variant="outlined"
      label={"Driver"}
      />
      )}
      value={value || null}
      />
   </Stack>
   )}
   />
</Grid>
<Grid item xs={12} sm={2}>
   <FormInputText
      name={`expense_lines.${index}.amount`}
      control={control}
      label={"Amount"}
      type={"number"}
      />
</Grid>
<Grid item md={1}>
   <IconButton component="span" sx={{mt: 2}}
   onClick={() => remove(index)}>
   <RemoveIcon/>
   </IconButton>
</Grid>
</Grid>
))}
```

[On Render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DW9s4.png)
[On Submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFMaJ.jpg)